# Is there a better way to type keys of an object than this one (without writing out an interface for said object)?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following:

```
const obj = {
    a: {
        FIELD: 'fieldA',
    },
};

const objA: typeof obj['a'] = obj.a;

const { FIELD } = objA;

const someFunction = (FIELD: keyof typeof objA):keyof typeof objA  => FIELD

someFunction(FIELD as keyof typeof objA);
```

Typescript does not complain with this code.

However, I'd much prefer the last two lines to be akin to,

```
const someFunction = (FIELD) => FIELD

someFunction(FIELD);
```

Is there any way / a cleaner way to have TS infer the type of my object (and return type), without me having to write out an interface like,

```
interface IObj {
    a: {
        FIELD: string;
    }
};
```

Comment: I think that maybe your example doesn't do what you think. Agree with @Mahdi, that `keyof typeof objA` resolves to `'FIELD'`, which may not be what you want.

I'm confused as to what this code should achieve. Would you please give real-world usage?

Comment: I have an object `socketEvents` with an `on` property and a `emit` property, both properties containing respective socket event names. I was exporting `socketEvents` in two parts as `export const socketEventsOn = socketEvents.on` and  `export const socketEventsEmit = socketEvents.emit`. Importing these two threw TS compilation errors, spawning this OP/question

Comment: Please, edit your example - in on snippet, show the shortened implementation of the module that is exporting the `socketEventsOn`. And in a second snippet, show the module in which you're importing it, and also show the usage of the imported constants. I'm still unclear on what role the `someFunction` plays in your example

Answer (score 0):

Typescript types can be passed variables, like the interface:

```
interface IObj<T> {
   a: {
      FIELD: T
   }
}
```

Then this can be used in function, lets say you define a new function like this:

```
const func = (obj: IObj<string>) => obj
```

That would make TS understand that in the passed object, and in the returned object, FIELD property is always a string.

Comment: Oh right i believe i missed the parenthesis part of your title, in that case i guess this answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that `keyof typeof objA` resolves to `'FIELD'` which is a string, what I think you're looking for is the type of value of `FIELD` which is `typeof objA['FIELD']` or equivalently `Obj['a']['FIELD']`.

```
const obj = {
    a: {
        FIELD: 'fieldA',
    },
};

type Obj = typeof obj;

const objA = obj.a;

const { FIELD } = objA;

const someFunction = (field: Obj['a']['FIELD']) => field

someFunction(FIELD);
```